# How to clean up a LaTeX code in Overleaf (new to LaTeX and Overleaf)

Tags: line-spacing

I was recently solving a simple integral with LaTeX and I couldn't find a very clean way to do it. This is my work and I would like to know how to clean up the LaTeX both in the code and making how I can make it more readable on screen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\[ \int \frac{2x^3}{1+x^4} \,dx \]
\[u=x^4+1\]
\[\frac{du}{dx}=4x^3\]
\[du=4x^3\cdot dx \]
\[\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4} \,dx \]
\[=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u} \,du \]
\[=\frac{1}{2}\ln |u|\]
\[=\frac{\ln|x^4+1|}{2}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

This is very opinion based ... See, if you liked the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{2x^3}{1+x^4} \,dx    
    & \Rightarrow       \\
u   & = x^4+1           \\ 
\frac{du}{dx}
    & = 4x^3            \\ 
du  & = 4x^3\cdot dx    \\
\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4} \,dx
    & = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u} \,du = \frac{1}{2}\ln |u|    \\
    & = \frac{\ln|x^4+1|}{2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @jackson, you are welcome! BTW, you may consider to accept answer (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer)(.

Comment: Done, thank you!